# How to best go to the parent directory of a directory with std::filesystem in c++

Tags: c++, c++17

Say we have a filesystem::path pointing at a directory `/fo/bar/`.

How do i best get a path pointing to `/fo`?

Note:
The path::parent_path() is not sufficient here. It does only go back to the directory, but if the path is already pointing at a directory it does nothing.

Note2:
It seems like my problem was something like leaving a slash in the pathname, when trying without it works as expected. Nice.

Comment: [I can't reproduce your behaviour.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2953472c2e1bcf5b) I clearly have it pointing to a directory and it still returns the parent path. In addition, I don't understand your iterator point—path iterators model input iterators (and more in fact).

Comment: Wierd.. You're right. It does work. I tried it again and again, but apparently i did something wrong.

Comment: Ok, so like in the duplicate i must have hade a trailing slash in the pathname.